# how to search words or text from array using regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex, search

I have array which contains different text and I want to search given text from array but I can not success

Here is my code

```
$search_word= "Joust Bag";
$data = array("Foo", "Joust Duffle Bag","Bag", "Wayfarer Messenger", "Voyage Yoga", "pushit Messagenger");

preg_match("/(.*)$search_word(.*)/", $data, $output_array);

echo print_r($output_array); // it should be return "Bag" and "Joust Bag"
```

Comment: So each word in `$search_word` should be searched for on its own?

Comment: yes ,each array value match with $search_word variable value,if match then return relevant result. in my case it should be return "Bag" and "Joust Bag"

Comment: `print_r` is a function, not a variable, remove the dollar sign

Comment: Your data does not contain a "Joust Bag", just a "Joust Duffle Bag"

Comment: I know it,but if search word is Joust Bag ,it should return Joust Duffle Bag,and Bag result..therefore I am trying to achieve by regular expression

Comment: therefore I want like result not equal result